# MYSQL INSERT QUERY NOT WORKING SHOWING ERROR "Database_Exception [ 1241 ]: Operand should contain 1 column(s)"

Tags: mysql

I have tried MySQL insert query that is not working and showing Error "Database_Exception [ 1241 ]: Operand should contain 1 column(s)".

====>INSERT QUERY

```
INSERT INTO `notifications` (`message`, `selected_numbers`, `creation_date`, `update_date`, `message_date`)
     VALUES ('hello testing',
              ('32', '655', '203', '205', '204', '202', '12', '497', '123', '949', '77', '942', '937', '944', '953', '565', '652', '440', '826', '290', '20', '172', '23', '271', '648', '91', '89', '90', '450', '92', '31', '770', '766', '734', '776', '376', '403', '66', '977', '616', '65', '379', '323', '841', '745', '428', '544', '22', '831', '787'), 
              1498889053, 1498889053, '07/01/2017');
```

I have tried to insert single record in pass array value.
but this query is not working.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you want each element of that list to go into a separate row, with the other 4 columns being the same.  If so, you can use `insert . . . select` and generate the rows in a subquery:

```
INSERT INTO `notifications` (`message`, `selected_numbers`, `creation_date`, `update_date`, `message_date`)
     SELECT 'hello testing', sn.selected_number,
            1498889053, 1498889053, '2017-07-01'
     FROM (SELECT '32' as selected_number UNION ALL
           SELECT '655' UNION ALL
           . . .
           SELECT '787'
          ) sn
```

Answer (score 0):

> INSERT INTO `notifications` (`message`, `selected_numbers`, `creation_date`, `update_date`, `message_date`)
>        VALUES ('hello testing',
>                 ('32', '655', '203', '205', '204', '202', '12', '497', '123', '949', '77', '942', '937', '944', '953', '565', '652', '440', '826', '290', '20', '172', '23', '271', '648', '91', '89', '90', '450', '92', '31', '770', '766', '734', '776', '376', '403', '66', '977', '616', '65', '379', '323', '841', '745', '428', '544', '22', '831', '787'), 
>                 1498889053, 1498889053, '07/01/2017');

Instead of making this query, just exclude the array for 'selected_numbers' and execute the query like below.

**Code**

$notifications_id = Model_Notifications::insert($validatedValues->as_array());

**Query**

> INSERT INTO `notifications` (`message`,`creation_date`, `update_date`, `message_date`)
>        VALUES ('hello testing',1498889053, 1498889053, '07/01/2017');

then for storing the 'selected_numbers' array make a new table and store it against the primary key of the above executed query.

**Code**

```
foreach ($phonenumber_value as $phone_id){
                Model_Notifications::notifications($phone_id, $notifications_id);
            }
```